# Cannot start renderd service for mod_tile

Tags: apache, openstreetmap, mapnik

I am building an OSM tile server as per directions available here: https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-16-04-2-lts/ on an Amazon EC2 instance with Ubuntu 16-04 LTS.

Everything is working well until the step of starting renderd as a service:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/renderd start
```

This returns an error of: "Job for renderd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status renderd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Checking the details mentioned gives messages like:

"renderd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203"

"The error number returned by this process is 8."

I can however run renderd directly no problem as below, and can even (slowly) load tiles into a leaflet map, I just cannot run it as a service.

```
sudo -u username renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
```

I have also tried changing to my rendering user and starting the service from there, but then I get a password prompt for user ubuntu (there isn't one).

What else can I test out or investigate to find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to start building my server again from scratch, this time also using information from other tutorials: https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-16-04 and https://ircama.github.io/osm-carto-tutorials/tile-server-ubuntu

Following those instructions, renderd now runs as a service. The main difference I noticed was those tutorials above use https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile.git rather than the 
https://github.com/SomeoneElseOSM/mod_tile.git source I used before, so perhaps the settings of the branched mod_tile were not compatible with my server.